# Updating property in VueJS on Laravel server post

Tags: jquery, laravel, vuejs2

I'm working on vuejs frontend with 'step wizards' and the display for each steps depends on the value saved on each step.
Meaning on each next/back button I'm doing a database post.

One solution could be using the mounted and calling an axios get
to populate my form variables which will definitely solve my issues.
But again will need to change and do a lot of

```
this.variable1 = response.data.variable1
this.variable2 = response.data.variable2
this.variable3 = response.data.variable3
this.variable4 = response.data.variable4
```

So was wondering if we can change the VueJS props: ['var'], on server post since we have already used the prop object (user object).

Example VueJS

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['user'],
  template: '<h3>{{ user }}
             <a href="#" @click="saveUser">Save</a>
            </h3>',

methods: {
  saveUser() {
        axios call here 
        and must change the user object
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically) is the answer.

Comment: please provide more code ?

Comment: In accepted answer there you can see how to merge already existing object `this` with object `response.data`.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: If you want to update the user prop and reflect this change to the parent you can implement the [v-model pattern](https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/) or use the [sync modifier](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/vues-v-model-directive-vs-sync-modifier-d1f83957c57c)